# Don't understand why i am getting an undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas

My code is basically up on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jekdhn1/.
I am playing around with canvas and animation.

My problem is that i am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined canvas2.js:39.

I am not seeing why i would get this error and it acts like it does see the value for x when running the script. If someone could tell me why i am getting this error and  how to fix it that would be great.
My script:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasTwo');
     canvas.width = 1000;
     canvas.height = 500;
  var circ = [];
  var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var cW = c.canvas.width, cH = c.canvas.height;
  var max = 20;

 function newCircle(){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cW) + 1;
    var y = 300;
    var r = 5;
    var cWidth = Math.floor( 5* Math.random());
    var cHeight = Math.floor( 5* Math.random());
    circ.push({"x":x,"y":y,"width":cWidth,"height":cHeight,"r":r});
}


function draw(){
    newCircle();
    for(var i=0;i<max;i++){
        c.fillStyle = 'rgba(163,219,91,0.3)';
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(circ[i].x+=3, circ[i].y+=.5, circ[i].r,0, 2* Math.PI, false);
        c.fill();
     if(circ[i].y > cH || circ[i].x>cW){
        circ.splice(i,1);
     }
   }
 };
 function animate(){
    c.save();
    c.clearRect(0, 0, cW, cH);
    draw();
    c.restore();
 }

 setInterval(animate, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much tells you what the problem is, you have this

```
circ[i].x
```

and it's telling you that there is no `x` property, so the object doesn't have such a property.
Either you iterated over the wrong numbers, so `i` doesn't reference anything in the array, or you simply didn't add a `x` property.

In this case, it's the former, and it's because you have an empty array

```
var circ = [];
```

then you start pushing to that array

```
circ.push({"x":x,"y":y,"width":cWidth,"height":cHeight,"r":r});
```

so the array starts at 0, and the first time you run the loop it only has one object inside it, and yet you've set `max` to `20` so you're iterating to 20, but there's only one single object at the zero index ?

If you want to limit to max 20, add a condition that uses the length if it's below the max value, like this

```
var val = circ.length < max ? circ.length-1 : max;

for(var i=0;i<val;i++){ ...
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jekdhn1/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating to `max`, however initially there are not `max` (20) numbers of items in `circ`. Change to:

```
for(var i=0;i<circ.length;i++)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jekdhn1/1/